# Incorrect size of entity collection from relation

Tags: jpa

I encountered strange problem while writting my application. I have two entities connected with bi-directional relation.

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries( value = {
    @NamedQuery( name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e")
})
public class Employee extends AbstractModel<Long, Employee>{
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable( name = "EMP_TASK", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "EMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "TASK_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Task extends AbstractModel<Long, Task>{
    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "tasks", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I'm querying for list of employees using NamedQuery `Employee.findAll` and sending it to jsp

```
@Override
protected void processDefaultAction() throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAll();
    request.setAttribute("employees", employees);
    forward("employees");
}
```

The problem  occurs when I'm trying to display Employee information  in  jsp with additional column Number of tasks which contains `${fn:length(emp.tasks)}`.

For some of the entities, the value displayed is lower than it should e.q. 2 instead  of 3 ( in database 3 relations exists for given employee ). However when I change servlet code to:

```
@Override
protected void processDefaultAction() throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<>();
    for(Employee emp : employeeService.findAll())
        employees.add(employeeService.find(emp.getId()));
    request.setAttribute("employees", employees);
    forward("employees");
}
```

everything is displayed properly. 
It looks like fetching all employees at once with their relations wasn't working properly. Any idea what can  be the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you add an employee, you add that employee to the tasks' employees set, and vice versa.

Also don't forget to merge the changes.

For example:

```
public void addEmployee(Task task, EntityManager m) {
  Employee emp = new Employee();
  emp.add(task);
  task.employees.add(emp);

  m.persist(emp);
  m.merge(task);
}

public void addTask(Employee emp, EntityManager m) {
  Task task = new Task();
  task.add(emp);
  emp.tasks.add(task);

  m.persist(task);
  m.merge(emp);
}
```